Algunos componentes de Ionic no se Renderizan en el APK
Estoy compilando una aplicacion de Ionic con Angular version 17 usando componentes Standadlone.
La aplicacion funciona perfectamente en modo de desarrollo, con el comando
ionic serve

Sin embargo, cuando realizo la construccion de la APK, usando capacitor, funciona pero los componentes tales como

Action sheets
Search Bar

nativos de Ionic, no se renderizan o su funcionalidad esta rota.
Adjunto una imagen ejecutandose en el navegador, y otra en un movil. Si necesitan informacion adicional pueden decirme, gracias por su ayuda.
Navegador

Movil


Depura la aplicación en el dispositivo para ver si está lanzando algún error.

Intente depurarla, sin embargo solo me aparece en la consola el error de unimplemented. Pero este error solo aparece al cargar la app, el searchbar y el action-sheet no arrojan ningun error

posiblemente estés importando los componentes orientados a arquitectura modular; lo cual, entraría en conflicto con angular 17+ (arquitectura standalone). Si es éste el caso, solo tendrías que modificar la ruta de importación:
Componentes modulares:
import {IonSearchbar, IonActionSheet } from '@ionic/angular';
Componentes standalone:
import {IonSearchbar, IonActionSheet } from '@ionic/angular/standalone';
Espero te sea de ayuda...
